# TYPO3 pass controller context to ajax request

Tags: ajax, module, typo3, action, backend

I am working on a TYPO3-backend-module. The main "overview"-Action allows to upload a file via ajax upload, which gets processed in one of my controllers.

The corresponding controller-action instantiates a `StandaloneView`, renders it and writes the rendered content to the response body.
My problem is, that I have no `controllerContext` set in the generated content, therefore a form, which should trigger a different extbase action, in that rendered content does not work, because the modulename is not set.

Can anybody tell me how I could possibly get/pass the controllerContext, to make it available in the controller action, which is called via ajax ?
Best regards and thanks in advance, Oliver !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is that BE modules don't exactly use a standard View implementation - in the default implementation, they wrap around a StandaloneView which by definition has no controller context.

That being said, if you can change the way the View wraps around the StandaloneView, the controller context can be copied by doing:

```
$view->getRenderingContext()->setControllerContext($parentView->getRenderingContext()->getControllerContext());
```

Alternatively you may want to copy the entire rendering context rather than just the controller context.

Advise applies to TYPO3v8 only. On 7.6 you will need to copy the Request instead.

For usages outside of MVC context you will need to manually pass the original controller context values such as controller name and module name. That means the values must be part of the link you create and must be read by the receiving code (in whichever way that code's context requires) and then manually assigned to a Request you create and pass to the sub-view. Note that this is only necessary if those MVC context values actually change - if you always call the same action next, you can get the right result by simply hardcoding the desired extension name, module name, controller name and action in the form/link in the template you render from that AJAX controller.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your quick response ! Unfortunately, I don`t quite fully understand your hint : what do you mean with "View wraps around the StandaloneView" ? And where do I get the $parentView ? The action is called via ajax, do I miss something in the ajax-request maybe?

Comment: The example you gave indicates you are using a registered Extbase backend module (given that you say you create a new view and write a rendered response and wish for a controller context). If that is truly the case, the "parent view" is found in $this->view, but I'm beginning to think that this is not the case. You may need to further explain how your controller is registered and what the application actually does. It doesn't sound like the normal use case to return a complete form in XHR as response to a file upload so that part is also a bit unclear.

Comment: Ok I will give some more details : the purpose of the action being called, is to process a .csv-file, which is being uploaded using the same ajax call.
I registered the ajax-method via Configuration/Backend/AjaxRoutes.php and call it just like it is shown in any docs. Unfortunately there is no "$this" - since it is an ajax call, I am not in object context inside the controller-action that is requested via ajax.
The action itself prepares a confirmation-step and I want to provide a save-button sending the data to a different action afterwards

Comment: If this is the case then your controller completely lacks all MVC context (and isn't exactly a controller in that context). The recommendation if you actually need those things, is to make the receiving action *a standard module controller action* which automatically is fitted with full context of your module. The approach where you create a standalone view in detached code is not recommended but you can do it - I'll revise my answer above to include that option though it isn't recommended.